# strtoupper isn't working in my code

Tags: php

```
<?php
if(!empty($_POST['code'])){
$code = strtoupper($code);
$param[':code'] = $_POST['code'];
$sql .= 'AND `code` = :code';
}
?>
```

strtoupper don't working. Why? Any advices?

Comment: You need to define `$code` first. You can't `strtoupper()` what doesn't exist.

Comment: You're not using the result. `$code = strtoupper($code)` but after that you're using the original `$_POST['code']`, which is still lowercase.

Comment: Here `if(!empty($_POST['code'])){
$code = $_POST['code'];
$code = strtoupper($code);` *give that a whirl*

Comment: and if that fails ^ then your POST array failed/html form and/or something else you didn't share

Comment: Are you building a SQL statement here? If so, this is not a secure way to do it - you may introduce a SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: not working.. ppl dont give me that - sign.. ihave searched for answer and dont find it, tahts why i asked here...

Comment: @halfer take a close look, it's the secure way, as it's my code, I'm building the parameter array for the prepared statement cf http://stackoverflow.com/a/43381191/5546267

Comment: Ooh, nice work @Blag - bound parameters!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$code` is useless, just use `$_POST`

```
if(!empty($_POST['code'])){
    $param[':code'] = strtoupper($_POST['code']);
    $sql .= 'AND `code` = :code';
}
```

Comment: Blag u are awesome, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to sanitize this.  As it appears you are trying to build a SQL query.

However, try something like this...

```
<?php
if(!empty($_POST['code'])){
    $code = strtoupper($code);
    $sql .= 'AND `code` = ' . $code;
}
?>
```